# How to check if Mobile Antenna is working or not?

Tags: android, mobile

I would like to diagnose the phone to check if the mobile antenna is working or not.
Does android provide any API to check this? 
If not, please suggest me how to do this.

thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you exactly mean with Mobile Antenna? The network connectivity?

Comment: @Mark : the case where the phone fails to register/connect to a network due to the antenna not working

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "antenna not working".

Comment: @CommonsWare : I mean the failure of hardware (transmitter/antenna) that is necessary for connecting/registering the mobile phone to the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API to check for hardware failures. Since the antennas for most mobile devices is integrated into the case, the odds of the antenna breaking and the device still remaining functional are fairly low.

> If not, please suggest me how to do this.

Build your own phone that has your own detection logic (hardware and software) to detect a broken antenna.

Comment: Can I use this from the android SMS Manager 'RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF'. I mean, I would write code to send an SMS, and when the radio is dead, I might get the response 'RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF' from the OS? would this be applicable in my case?

Comment: @3vikram: "off" != "failure of hardware".